# QCommandLineOption with optional value

Tags: qt

I would like to define a command-line option with an optional value. For example:

```
QCommandLineOption pngOption("png",
    QCoreApplication::translate("main", "Generate PNG diagrams."),
    "items", "*");
```

I'd like to use this option as follows:

```
myApp --png diagrams
myApp --png
```

The second usage is --png without a value (optional value) and causes an error "missing value after --png". I would think that in that case the value of the option should be set to the defaultValue argument of the QCommandLineOption constructor, which is provided as "*". But apparently, Qt does not do this.

So, my questions are:

- how to specify an option with an optional value (e.g., --png [items])
- what is the defaulValue argument of the QCommandLineOption
  constructor used for, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are providing a values to option instead use option without any arguments and positional option.

This is a copy from [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html#details) and tweaked to match your code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("my-copy-program");
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion("1.0");

    QCommandLineParser parser;
    parser.setApplicationDescription("Test helper");
    parser.addHelpOption();
    parser.addVersionOption();
    parser.addPositionalArgument("source", QCoreApplication::translate("main", "Source file."));

    // A boolean option with a single name (-p)
    QCommandLineOption generatePNGdiagrams("png", QCoreApplication::translate("main", "Generate PNG diagrams."));
    parser.addOption(generatePNGdiagrams);
    parser.process(app);

    const QStringList args = parser.positionalArguments();
    const QString filename = args.at(0);

    bool shouldGeneratePNGdiagrams = parser.isSet(generatePNGdiagrams);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm aware of positional options and I will need to use at least one. But here is a problem, because now I need to distinguish between an (optional) value for --png and a true positional option. This looks like a mess...